# matlab: figure size, same axis size

Tags: matlab, resize, scaling, figure

I have a figure with fixed size, like that:

```
hFig = figure(1);
set(hFig, 'Position', [200 200 500 500])
```

But the thing is, that I want to have my AXIS with fixed size (i want them to be a square), not (necessary) the whole figure... - see image attached, Y axis is a bit longer than X axis (of course longer in a meaning of display... X and Y axis range is set to the same value). How to adjust it?

Thanks!

[image: particle trajectory]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `axis equal` to set the spacing of the axis to be the same.